# "This is a new users answer to an old question" but answer is dated January 2013?

Tags: support

I found [this](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/review/late-answers/31335) in my *Late answers* review queue:

[image]

The question itself is from 2012 and it has answers from 2014.

I'm very curious why this would end up in the review queue now, in july 2015...  It was not a test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At first glance, it looked like a bug, but upon further inspection it appears this is indeed a normal system function.  In this case, the user did indeed post the answer back in 2013, but at the time the user's reputation was greater than 10, high enough to where this review queue filter wouldn't catch it.

However, recently, this post received two downvotes, putting the user's reputation below 10. When the job ran that checks the answers, the conditions to mark it as a late answer by a new user were true, and it was then added to the review queue.

For more information, see [Late Late Answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222413/155826).

Comment: Ah! Surprising. And I can't mark my own question as a duplicate, because that one is on meta.SE ;-)